# ffmpeg Mimic Eye Movement Pan Zoom on jpg of Handwriting

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have 2844 × 3218 jpgs of handwritten pages. I would like to ffmpeg zoompan over them in a way that mimics reading. Additional problem is that they will be combined with other movie clips that are 720x480 (so I think the zoom would have to be pretty close-in and the pan quite slow, ie. small video image size and want to be readable).
I have combed the interwebs looking for a zoompan tutorial suitable for a beginner like myself, but man... it's a hodgepodge of confusion and whoa, could someone please do a series of entry-level zoompan and video filters tutorials?

(Edit) Maybe we could start here. This creates a movie of the image scrolling down. I see the bottom of the page first and it scrolls down. How would I alter this code to make it go in reverse, see the top of the image first and then have it scroll up?

`ffmpeg -i 2844x3218image.jpg \
  -filter_complex \
    "pad=w=9600:h=6000:x='(ow-iw)/2':y='(oh-ih)/2',\
    zoompan=x='(iw-0.625*ih)/2':y='(1-on/(25*4))*(ih-ih/zoom)'\
    :z='if(eq(on,1),2.56,zoom+0.002)':d=25*4:s=720x480" \
  -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 720x480movie.mp4`

(Edit 2)
Scrolls up, why?

`ffmpeg -i 2844x3218image.jpg \
  -filter_complex \
    "pad=w=9600:h=6000:x='(ow-iw)/2':y='(oh-ih)/2',\
    zoompan=x='(iw-0.625*ih)/2+ih*0.625-ih*1.6/zoom' \
    :y='(on/(25*30))*(ih-ih/zoom)'\
    :z='if(eq(on,1),2.56,zoom+0.002)':d=25*30:s=720x480,\
format=yuv420p" 720x480movie3.mp4`

My zoompan would divide the input jpg into 4 parts. Set the zoom fairly high, pan right across the image, then quickly pan left back to section 2, then slowly pan right etc. etc. until the entire page had been viewed. This seems completely doable if I knew math & ffmpeg ;-)

Comment: The effect you're looking for is often called Ken Burns. That might bring up more examples.

Comment: Thanks, the best tutorial I found so far was indeed called Ken Burns Effect Slideshows with FFMPeg . But there are enough missing pieces that I can't quite get my head around what is doing what. [Ken Burns Effect Slideshows with FFMPeg](https://el-tramo.be/blog/ken-burns-ffmpeg/)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know ffmpeg at all, I've done this kind of thing in Final Cut, but I've never tried scripting it. Maybe see if you can hone down which bit isn't making sense & ask a new question?